# Use xargs to move files from within a directory

Tags: find, wildcards, xargs

I am searching for some folders in my current directory. What I want to do is, move all the files within those directories to another directory. I am using the following command:

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regex 'myRegexExpHere' | xargs -I file mv file/* Desktop/New\ folder/
```

But as expected, the '*' is not expanded by xargs, instead searching for a file named * in each folder. What should I do to achieve my aim? Please suggest ways involving the use of xargs only (and not the -exec switch of find), primarily because I have read that using xargs is much more efficient.

Comment: `find -exec … +` is even more efficient than `xargs`. And further, it probably doesn't matter—the moves themnselves will most likely be the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I will have to resort to -exec if I don't get any other solution. Besides, as you said, the move part is the major time-hogger, so it probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

You need the expansion of the wildcard to happen in a shell that's executed after `file` has been replaced by the name of the matching file. So you need to start a shell from `xargs`.

Better than using `xargs`, use the `exec` predicate to `find`. It's simpler and doesn't suffer from quoting issues.

```
find -maxdepth 1 -regex 'myRegexExpHere' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0"/* Desktop/New\ folder/' {} \;
```

You're probably overcomplicating things. This simple use of `find` can be expressed directly in most shells. Ksh has a syntax for regular expressions:

- `@(EXPR1|EXPR2)` matches `EXPR1` or `EXPR2`
- `*(EXPR)` matches 0 or more occurrence of `EXPR`
- `+(EXPR)` matches 1 or more occurrence of `EXPR`
- `?(EXPR)` matches 0 or 1 occurrence of `EXPR`

This syntax is also available in bash if you run `shopt -s extglob` first, and in zsh if you run `setopt ksh_glob` first. Then you can use

```
mv REGEX/* Desktop/New\ folder/
```

Answer (score 1):

Why use `find` when you don't need recursion? Use the shell (I'm assuming Bash here, modify to suit your needs) for regex matching:

```
for dir in */;do
    if [[ "$dir" =~ yourRegexHere ]];then
        mv -- "$dir"/* "Desktop/New folder/"
    fi
done
```

If your shell's regex capabilities are too weak for your requirements, it doesn't get any better than Perl:

```
perl -e 'for(grep {/yourRegexHere/} glob "*/"){ 
             qx(mv -- "$_"/* "Desktop/New folder") 
         }'
```

Comment: So I should always try to use a loop when I need to perform such operations? What are the cases then where a single command would benefit me?